Coefficient for squared term of parabola
Is there a descriptive term for the coefficient of the squared polynomial term for the parabola? This would be represented by the coefficient $a$ in the functional form:
$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$
For background, this is for an optimization problem involving a parabolic objective function, so the 'intensity' of the gradient will increase with an increase in this term.

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It’s the leading coefficient

From a geometrical point of view, $a=1/(4f)$, where $f$ is the focal length.

It’s the leading coefficient; that term is used for polynomials in general, not just quadratics.
